# How can I get a custom UITableViewCell from a TableView using cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, custom-cell

I have a table in one of my views, I want to use the table to allow the user to input data. To do this I created a custom UITableViewCell which worked perfectly.

My problem occurred when trying to get the text out of each cell. I have had a look through all the documentation and can't find any solution. Any help would be much appreciated!

The code for this method is:

```
    Subject *subject = [self.arrayOfSubjects objectAtIndex:i];

    AddSubjectDetailsCell *cell;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndex:i];
    cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    subject.title = cell.subjectTitleField.text;
    subject.room = cell.subjectRoomField.text;
    subject.teacher = cell.subjectTeacherField.text;
```

Does anyone have a way of converting a regular cell to a custom one or another way to extract the text from the text field?

Thanks!

Comment: how does your custom cell look like? does it extends from the uitableviewcell or you are just using the uitableviewcell and put custom view in it?

Answer (score 1):

You are already getting an instance of `AddSubjectDetailsCell` back, it is just being returned to you typed as the parent type `UITableViewCell` because that is all the `UITableView` knows.  All you've got to do is cast it to it's specific type like this:

```
AddSubjectDetailsCell *cell;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndex:i];
cell = (AddSubjectDetailsCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

@Timothy's answer might be a solution, but why don't you link model objects to the custom cells cells on instantiation?

Instead of querying the UI in the end **you could update your model right in the cell implementation**.

I'd definitely add a weak reference to the corresponding `Subject` for each cell, then update it on cell user actions as you go.

Some kind of design like this, even if not that encapsulated: http://eppz.eu/blog/custom-uitableview-cell/